# Помогите с регуляркой Java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

есть строка, мне нужно рассплитить её по пробелам и различным символам типа ,-!.-= и т.д, как будет выглядеть регулярное выражение? 
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Будущим читателям `.split("[\\p{Punct}\\s]+"`

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "asd qwe!zxc.ggg-qqq,www-rrr=";
String[] split = s.split("[ ,!.\\-=]");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split)); // [asd, qwe, zxc, ggg, qqq, www, rrr]
```